# Whenever I type 'import discord' I get an error message on Python 3.6

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to make a discord bot for my server. I've downloaded an older version of Python hoping that it would work, but whenever I type "import discord" I get an error message. I also tried downloading discord again by doing "python -m pip install discord.py==0.16.12" from a tutorial on making discord bots, but it says "requirement already satisfied."

When I type "import discord" I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Discord'"

[a picture of 'import discord' error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSjuF.png)

["requirement already satisfied" image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHDLH.png)

Thank you for reading and helping me out! :)

Comment: Are you using enviroments?

Comment: These things are usually a conflict or mismatch between environments when you have multiple python installations or different environments configured.

Comment: I'm brand new to coding, I'm not sure what that is yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'environments' are

Comment: Please include error messages, code, and other text directly in your question. External resources may disappear in the future, making your question unhelpful for future visitors.

Comment: Yeah, try to avoid image links, you can paste actual code or messages as text and format them properly instead. Now, do you have multiple python versions installed? Uninstall all extra ones that you installed perhaps.

Comment: I do have multiple versions of Python installed. I'm just worried that if I uninstall Python 3.6 then  won't be able to make my discord bot.

Comment: @Prog Girl I think what they mean is you want to work in a virtual environment where it's much easier to organise everything.

Also if you have multiple versions of Python installed, discord package might be installed with Python 2.7 and not 3.6. Try doing "python3 -m pip install discord.py" to install it with 3.6

Comment: @ZWang I just tried it, and the command prompt says: 'pyton3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Darn it.

Comment: @ProgGirl Try "Python --version" and post the output

Comment: @ZWang it is version 3.7.2

Comment: @ProgGirl Just noticed your error code was "pyton3". Did you miss type the command into terminal?